# rails 4 hide a model attribute before rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a user model using Rails 4 activerecord, it has a accesstoken attribute which store personal access token to authenticate this user as a alternative authentication mechanism.

As rails rendern by json render all fields of a model, access token field is also rendered. This is dangerous to leak credential information.

How could I filter the accesstoken field before rendering and also mark it as 'FILTERED' whenever it shows in server log, just like 'password' field does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JSON you can override [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) on the model:

```
def as_json(options={})
  options.reverse_merge! except: :accesstoken
  super(options)
end
```

For the logging, in `config/application.rb` you can add the attribute to the filter list

```
config.filter_parameters << :accesstoken
```